# DHCP Configuration in ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Tags: dhcp

I know i  can configure DHCP in terminal by installing isc-dhcp-server but what i need is the

best GUI program that allow me to configure DHCP settings graphically .

Any Suggestion is thankful ?

Comment: please i need an answers ?

Comment: i dont think that no one in this site know the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try webmin

install webmin web interface and add dhcp server module

```
 sudo apt-get install webmin
```

there are a lot of options in this great interface